# Asymptote does not produce an output when run on files in another directory

Tags: asymptote

I have a file called `test1.asy` in the current directory. I can run `asy test1.asy` and it produces a `test1.eps` output file normally. I also have another directory in the current directory called `asy_src` with another asymptote file `test2.asy` inside it. However, when I run `asy asy_src/test2.asy`, it neither produces an output file nor an error message. Is there something wrong with my Asymptote set up, and how can I fix it? For the sake of an example, please assume that both `test1.asy` and `test2.asy` contain the same code as follows. My Asymptote version is 2.78.

```
size(10cm);
pair A = dir(120);
pair B = dir(210);
pair C = dir(330);
draw(A--B--C--cycle);
```

Comment: I tried, and I get test.eps in the current directory.

Comment: @Sergio I see. I think my mistake was that I named both files to be test.asy. As a result, I was confused why it was not producing a new .eps file in any of the directories. Thanks for your reply.